# Converting extracted text string to date where string varies in length in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, materialized-views, regexp-replace, to-date

I have a materialized view of a text column that extracts a string of numbers representing a date.

The materialized view is created using the following function:

```
(regexp_replace(left(substring(lower(replace(content,' ','_')) from 're-inspection_date:_(.*)_'),10),'\D','','g'))
```

And outputs a text string in the format of MMDDYYYY **except** it **does not** account for leading zeroes for single-digit months and days.

When I try to use the "to_date" function specifying the format MMDDYYYY using the following:

```
(to_date(regexp_replace(left(substring(lower(replace(content,' ','_')) from 're-inspection_date:_(.*)_'),10),'\D','','g'),'MMDDYYYY'))
```

I get the error "date/time field value out of range: '12122018'".

I believe the issue is due to one or both of the following reasons:

- The resulting strings from my current regexp in the materialized view vary in length (e.g. 12212018 8222018 962018) due to my regexp removing all non-integer characters. The dates are 6, 7 or 8 digits long.
- As a result, I haven't yet been able to come up with a way of inserting a delimiter between the month/day/year values.

**Is there a way to make change these output strings to date format without changing my regexp?**

**If not, how could I change my regexp for extracting these values?**

Bear in mind that the date I'm after in the source text is formatted as 12/1/2018 and also doesn't account for leading 0's in days or months. Also, there is another date preceding the target date in the text formatted the same way.

Here is a sample of the source text:

> PLACEHOLDER TEXT FOR REDACTED STUFF BLAH BLAH BLAH
>    **** Loremipsum
>   11/28/2018 4: 21: 37  PM  ****1  of 2 Facility Information Permit 
>   Number: 12-34-56789 Name  of Facility: Dolor sit amet-consectetur
>   Address: 123 Fake  Street City, Zip: adipiscing  elit12345 RESULT: sed 
>   Do Eiusmod tempor: by 8: 00 AM Re-Inspection Date: 12/4/2018  Type: Blah-Type  Stuff Etc: Dolor sit amet-consectetur...

Where the "Re-Inspection Date: 12/4/2018" is what I'm after.

I'm on Postgres 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaushik Nayak is correct I guess. I get the same thing with this regex using a positive lookbehind (?<= Re-Inspection Date:) and allowing for any number of integers [0-9]* seperated with one slash /{1}

```
SELECT to_date(substring('string'
            from '(?<=Re-Inspection Date: )[0-9]*/{1}[0-9]*/{1}[0-9]*'), 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You may specify  varying lengths of integers using the repetition `{}` pattern

```
select to_date(substring(lower(content) 
from  're-inspection date:\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})' ),'mm/dd/yyyy') from t
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3f5a97f8270557a4062ca69c93e42563)